# NetSuite Advanced PDF Picking Sheet Printing Text As The Result of #if

Tags: netsuite

Using advanced pdf, I am trying to modify a picking sheet to print a statement when {shipcomplete} is Yes. I am using the <#if> but have issues when the field is null.

I tried the following

<#if record.shipcomplete?has_content>

<#if record.shipcomplete == "Yes">

SHIP COMPLETE

</#if></#if>

When I do so, I receive the error below.

If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??

I am not familiar with the myoptionalvar and do not know how to incorporate it into the picking sheet.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing the first line to <#if record.shipcomplete??>